# weird variable issue is IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am having a weird issue in IE.

I have

The tool variable can be empty and it seems like that I need to have 
`tool==''` to make IE happy.

```
//work in IE and other browsers..
  if(tool==null || tool==''){Alert('bang!!!');}

//doesn't work in IE but not other browsers.
  if(tool==null){Alert('bang!!!');}
```

What's going on here?

Comment: What **_doesn't work in IE but not other browsers_**?

Comment: also: I see a jquery tag, but no jquery code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if( !tool ){
  Alert('bang!!!');
}
```

Here, `!tool` will return `true` if `tool = null` or `tool = ''`.

Answer (score 0):

This article:
http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html
explains it very well.

You can use `if(!tool) alert('bang');`